# Push Notification click for Xamarin Android API 33

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, android-api-33

I am receiving push notifications but when I click it its not going inside the app .

**My Firebase class**

```
 public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
 {
     try
     {
         var body = message.GetNotification().Body;
         SendNotification(body, message.Data);
         Preferences.Set("NotificationIconUpdate", true);
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.SetAction("");
         intent.PutExtra("", "");
         SendBroadcast(intent);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         global.ShowToast(ex);
     }
 }

 void SendNotification(string messageBody, IDictionary<string, string> data)
 {
     try
     { GetString(Resource.String.pushNotification));
         intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
         intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
         foreach (var key in data.Keys)
         {
             string value = data[key];
             intent.PutExtra(key, value);
         }

         var flag = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O
         ? PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent | PendingIntentFlags.Immutable
         : PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent;

         var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, SplashActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, flag);

         var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, SplashActivity.CHANNEL_ID)
             .SetContentTitle(Constants.eGoldFax)
             .SetContentText(messageBody)
             .SetAutoCancel(true)
             .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
             .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_notification)
             .SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityDefault)  // Set the correct priority here
             .SetSound(RingtoneManager.GetDefaultUri(RingtoneType.Notification))  // Specify the sound URI
             .SetColor(ContextCompat.GetColor(Application.Context, Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));

         var notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.From(this);
         notificationManager.Notify(SplashActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());

         StartForeground(SplashActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.Build());



     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         global.ShowToast(ex);
     }
 }
```

**My create channel in main Launcher Page**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        var channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "FCM Notifications", NotificationImportance.Default)
        {
            Description = "Firebase Cloud Messages appear in this channel",
            Importance = NotificationImportance.Max

        };
        var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.NotificationService);
        notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);

    }
```

When I click the notification its not going inside the app in Android API 33.

When I click the push notification I need it to navigate to the app but the notification vanishes and not taking me inside the app.

Comment: Did this problem only appeared on the android 13?